# Python OOP init Argument Error

Tags: python, oop, initialization

So here's my code:

```
class Board:
    def __init__ (self, boardLength, boardHeight, pieces):
        self.__boardLength = boardLength
        self.__boardHeight = boardHeight
        self.__pieces = pieces
        self.__snapShots = []
        self.__tiles = []
        while len(self.__tiles) < (self.__boardHeight*self.__boardLength):
            self.__tiles.append(0)

board1 = Board(5, 4,
    [u,I_shape(1,'I'),X_shape(3,5,'U'),T_shape(4,5,'U'),L_shape(3,5,'U')]
)
```

and I get this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

I understand that init take 4 arguements, but one of them is self and I gave it the other three. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `__init__` for I_shape?  That's a call that gives three arguments (the implicit `self` plus the two you give).

Comment: I had to try and fix the code formatting on this like 3 times. Its so hard to read.

Comment: The thing you might be missing is the rest of the context surrounding the TypeError. That should tell you exactly where the crash is occurring, and as @Lattyware suggests in the answer, its most likely in the I_shape class and not this Board class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine your problem is actually in `I_shape`, given your other shapes all take 3 arguments. I ran this and it worked fine, replacing the classes that don't exist with `None`.

Also, it's worth noting that using name mangling (`__variable`) is not needed 99.9% of the time. Use a single underscore if you want to indicate it's private.

Comment: @Lattyware: You were quick. When I was just browsing, you already had an answer.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades I just happened to sit down and take a look as the question got asked. I'm forever writing an answer then having someone post the same thing just as I hover over the submit button XD.